# Bind a textbox to a textbox

Tags: c#, binding

I'm binding textboxes to an object as follows:

```
tPostcodeInvoice.DataBindings.Add("Text", 
                                  oAdressInvoice, 
                                  "zip", 
                                  true, 
                                  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

But what i now need to do is bind a textbox directly to another textbox then enable to ability to remove that binding, is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to bind to the textbox and not to the value the first textbox uses?

Comment: The first textbox has a binding to a specific object, i dont want to bind the second textbox to the same object but want to bind it to the first textbox when a checkbox is selected. There are various reasons why i want to do this that go outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming names of your textboxes are `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text",
                          textBox2,
                          "Text",
                          true,
                          DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```